# time and work problem

Tags: linear-algebra

A man can begin a work at his maximum rate; but afterwards the rate at which he works follows a cyclic pattern. Every 2 hr,it reduces by half but after 8 hrs,it comes back to its maximum level.He can complete a job in 151 Hrs at his maximum rate.How many hours would he take to complete the job if his rate follows the cyclic pattern?

Options are:

A. 301
B. 601
C. 641
D. 321

i am unable to understand this question.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is the following :

- 0h $\rightarrow$ 2h : Work rate = 100% efficiency
- 2h $\rightarrow$ 4h : Work rate = 50% efficiency
- 4h $\rightarrow$ 6h : Work rate = 25% efficiency
- 6h $\rightarrow$ 8h : Work rate = 12.5% efficiency

And every time he reaches 8 hours of work, he gets back to 0h and works at 100% efficiency for 2 hours, etc.

The question is : if the worker was working at 100% every time, he would need 151 hours to get the job done. However he doesn't work at 100% every time, so you have to use the cycle to determine how long it would take.

Comment: thank u so much for ur response. can u help me little bit more

Comment: @lata. You also need to identify how many different periods of efficiency are in $151$ hours.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici why ?

Comment: @T_O. I suppose that this is part of the trap (problem, I mean). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Thank you so much

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not sure what you mean. The way I see it (maybe it's not a good way) is the following : he accomplishes 1 unit of the task in 2 hours, and he needs to complete 75.5 units of the task. Then you just need to compute how many units is 1 cycle, and to be careful on the last cycle.

Comment: @T_O. Your way is very good for sure. You picked what I was meaning : **be careful on the last cycle**. Cheers.

Comment: @T_O. So, I see that you are in Paris. Have a look to my profile.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Comme quoi, les mathématiques sont avant tout une affaire de français ;) Si MSE vous plait je suis content pour vous !

Comment: @T_O. What are you doing in Paris and where ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm currently in an internship in Barcelona, but I'm studying statistics, economics & finance in Paris after 2 years of "classes préparatoires". Current school is ENSAE

Comment: @T_O. Congratulations and good luck !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you too!

Answer (score -1):

$a= \text{maximum efficiency}$
$$X\times \frac{(a+\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{4}+\frac{a}{8})}{4} = a\times 151$$ solving for $x$ we get $$x=151\times \frac{32}{15} =321$$
$X$ gives us the effective working time